# Is it possible to have more than one naming conventions of github posts?

Tags: ruby, github, markdown, jekyll, liquid

Is it possible to have *more than one* naming conventions of github posts?

For example, in the `_post` directory, I would like to have files like these:

```
2013-03-18-xyz.markdown  
abc.markdown
```

so that the generated HTML pages from them may be found at URLs:

```
http://username.github.com/2013/03/18/xyz.html

http://username.github.com/abc.html
```

respectively, for some suitable permalink(s?) configured in `_config.yml`.

Comment: I believe you are talking about

Comment: @HunterDolan: talking about ... *what*?

Comment: @StevenPenny: What you agree with? What did he say? All I see an incomplete sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, it should be possible by defining the permalink format for each post
https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Permalinks

> You can specify the permalinks for your site through the Configuration or on the YAML Front Matter for each post. You’re free to choose one of the built-in styles to create your links or craft your own. The default style is always date.

Notice the part `...for each post...`.

Comment: +1. That worked. BTW, can we follow naming convention other than `2013-03-18-xyz.markdown`?

Comment: No, not possible, you're stuck with this single convention. From the docs: `The format of these files is important, as named as YEAR-MONTH-DAY-title.MARKUP. The Permalinks can be adjusted very flexibly for each post, but the date and markup language are determined solely by the file name.` -- https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/usage

Answer (score 2):

> Notice the part ...for each post....

I would say the more important quote is this

> You can specify the permalinks for your site through the Configuration **or on the YAML Front Matter** for each post.

This means instead of even using the `_config.yml` perhaps you could just start a post like this

```
---
layout: post
title: Coderay
tags: Windows
permalink: /:year/:month/:title
---
```

Comment: +1. That worked. BTW, can we follow naming convention other than `2013-03-18-xyz.markdown`?